# How to summarize(add) a column according to same year and plot in R?

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2, rstudio

I have following type of data. But I would like to have graph with X-axis as Year and add all the sales added up in that year on Y- axis.

The Data frame name is salesdata. I have nearly 8000 rows of data. and the column headers are in the picture below.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### **Step 1: Changing dates to years**

First you can change your column of dates (Order_Date) to simply years by using this formula:

```
> salesdata$Order_Date = format(salesdata$Order_Date, "%Y")
```

This will give your Order Dates just the year the sales was done in.

### **Step 2: Summarizing your sales data**

After this you can create a vector with the summarizations of your sales data per year. This can be done using tapply:

```
> tapply(salesdata$Sales, salesdata$Order_Date, FUN=sum)
```

This will give you an overview of the total sales per year.

### **Step 3: Plotting your graph**

You can use barplot() to plot your bar chart using the values you got in your tapply function.

### **One-liner**

The function as a oneliner:

```
> barplot(tapply(salesdata$Sales, format(salesdata$Order_Date, "%Y"), FUN=sum))
```

Of course you can edit your graph to your liking.

[image: Example of the bar chart]

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1: Summarizing

You can use the `dplyr` package for that purpose, as:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(Order_Date) %>% 
  summarise(Sales = sum(Sales))
```

OR, this approach will work as well,

```
x %>% 
  group_by(Order_Date) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

#### Step 2: Plot

Once you're done with it, use `ggplot` to draw a plot of your interest, just use the respective function.

#### Additional Resources

For more details visit these blogs-

- [Plot Weekly or Monthly Totals in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/plot-weekly-or-monthly-totals-in-r/)
- [Transforming subsets of data in R with by, ddply and data.table](http://www.magesblog.com/2012/06/transforming-subsets-of-data-in-r-with.html)
- [Group data and plot multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349096/group-data-and-plot-multiple-lines)

Hope it helps!